# How to sort a list in Haskell in command line ghci

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

I am new to Haskell, and I want to make 1 function that will take two lists and merge then together, and then sort the combined list from smallest to biggest.
this should be done in the command line without using modules.

This is what i currently have, I am having trouble getting the "sortList" function to work, and also I do not know how to combine these 3 lines into 1 function.

```
let combineList xs ys = xs++ys
let zs = combineList xs ys
let sortList (z:zs) = if (head zs) < z then (zs:z) else (z:(sortList zs))
```

Comment: Do you need to write your own sorting algorithm?  If not, I would suggest importing `Data.List` and using the `sort` function.  Then you could just write it as `combineAndSort xs ys = sort (xs ++ ys)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bit awkward to define a sorting function within the ghci. I thing the easiest way to do it would be to write the sorting function in a file, and then loading it into ghci. For instance, you could write this concise (though not in-place!) version of quicksort in a file called `sort.hs` (taken from [the HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction#Quicksort_in_Haskell)):

```
quicksort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
quicksort []     = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
    where
        lesser  = filter (< p) xs
        greater = filter (>= p) xs
```

and load it into ghci:

```
> :l sort.hs
```

If you really want to define the function in ghci, you can do something like this (from [the Haskell user's guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html)):

```
> :{
> let { quicksort [] = []
>     ; quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort (filter (< p) xs)) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort (filter (>= p) xs))
>     }
> :}
```

once this is defined, you can do

```
> let combineAndSort xs ys = quicksort (xs ++ ys)
```

As another answer already explained, it would of course be quicker to just import sort from  `Data.List`, but it is definitely a good exercise to do it manually.

Your question suggests that you are a bit confused about the scope of variables in Haskell. In this line

```
> let combineList xs ys = xs++ys
```

you introduce the variables `xs` and `ys`. Mentioning them to the left of the equals sign just means that `combineList` takes two variables, and in the body of that function, you are going to refer to these variables as `xs` and `ys`. It doesn't introduce the names outside of the function, so the next line

```
> let zs = combineList xs ys
```

doesn't really make sense, because the names `xs` and `ys` are only valid within the scope of `combineList`. To make `zs` have a value, you need to give `combineList` some concrete arguments, eg.:

```
> let zs = combineList [2,4,6] [1,3,5]  --> [2,4,6,1,3,5]
```

But since the body of `combineList` is so simple, it would actually be easier to just do:

```
> let zs = [2,4,6] ++ [1,3,5] --> [2,4,6,1,3,5]
```

The last line is

```
> let sortList (z:zs) = if (head zs) < z then (zs:z) else (z:(sortList zs))
```

I think this line has confused you a lot, because there are quite a lot of different errors here. The answer by ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ mentions most of them, I would encourage you to try understand each of the errors he mentions.

Answer (score 29):

How to sort list in `ghci`:

```
Prelude> :m + Data.List
Prelude Data.List> sort [1,4,2,0]
[0,1,2,4]
```

About your functions

```
let combineList xs ys = xs++ys
```

What is a point to create another alias for append function? But if you're really wants one - it could be defined like `let combineList = (++)`.

```
let zs = combineList xs ys
```

It makes no sense because `xs` and `ys` are unknown outside of your `combineList`.

```
let sortList (z:zs) = if (head zs) < z then (zs:z) else (z:(sort zs))
```

This definition is not valid because it doesn't cover and empty list case and `(zs:z)` produces infinite type and `sort` is not defined yet. And you can get `head` of `zs` just by another pattern matching. And maybe you don't wanna to make another recursive call in the `then` part of `if` statement. And finally I should admit that this sorting algorithm doesn't work at all.